# Does activating a scroll require satisfying the spell's verbal and somatic components?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, spell-components

Example: The wizard is in the area of a [*silence*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#silence) spell effect and wants to activate a scroll. The spell on the scroll normally requires verbal and somatic components. Is the wizard prevented from activating the scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, unless the scroll is special

If a spell requires verbal or somatic components then casting if from a scroll does as well (unless the scroll is made with silent spell metamagic)

The 3.5 DMG solves this question right at the very start of the magic items section DMG (213) but neglects to repeat the information in the subsequent scroll section (237).

From DMG

> Scrolls are treated as as Spell Completion type of magical item: Spell
> Completion: This is the activation method for scrolls. A scroll is a
> spell that is mostly finished. The preparation is done for the caster,
> so no preparation time is needed beforehand as with normal
> spellcasting. **All that’s left to do is perform the short, simple,
> finishing parts of the spellcasting (the final gestures, words, and so
> on**). To use a spell completion item safely, a character must be of
> high enough level in the right class to cast the spell already. If he
> can’t already cast the spell, there’s a chance he’ll make a mistake
> (see Scroll Mishaps, page 238, for possible consequences). Activating
> a spell completion item is a standard action and provokes attacks of
> opportunity exactly as casting a spell does.

Comment: @Someone_Evil so, the answer is "yes, unless the scroll is special" or am I missing something? 
Both the questions "Does activating a scroll require satisfying the spell's verbal and somatic components?" and  "Is the wizard prevented from activating the scroll?" can be answered with a "yes", aren't they?

Comment: @Verdict00 Hmm.. the questions has been edited since I edited nicholas' answer. I've edited it again, and let's hope I didn't muck anything up

Comment: This answer could be improved by a quick example of what would make a scroll “special” (e.g. if it was scribed using /silent spell/ ). Already upvoted though, so it’s already good.